# Solr long strings before short while sort on sortTitle asc

Tags: solr

At the moment i have the following sort issue.
I have a list of products which i want to sort by title asc.

The list:

- Product zla
- Product bla
- Product
- Product cla

My query is the following in solr dashboard.

**FQ**

- type_stringS:product AND pid:110
- site:[www.localhost.com](http://www.localhost.com)

**Sort**

- sortTitle asc

I am using sortTitle instead of title, since title is tokenized in solr itself.

I expect

- Product
- Product bla
- Product cla
- Product zla

I get

- Product bla
- Product cla
- Product zla
- Product

Shouldn't "Product" be in the first place?

Comment: what is the fieldType for sortTitle? is it string or keywordTokeniser with lowercase filter factory?

Comment: try this fieldType for your field sortTitle <fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti We just use basics in solr and have no experience in editing this configuration. Thank you for the answer, but we chose for the solution of resorting the results with PHP asort

Comment: I think its should not be approach...But anyways its your call